# How to use stans integrate_ode x inputs?

Tags: ode, stan

Recently stan has added the `integrate_ode` method.  Unfortunately the only documentation I can find is the [stan reference manual](http://mc-stan.org/documentation/) (p.191ff). I have a model that would require some driving signal.  As I understand the parameter `x_r` and `x_i` are supposed to be used for this.

For the sake of a concrete example lets assume I want to implement the example from the documentation with following change:

```
 real[] sho(real t,
               real[] y,
               real[] theta,
               real[] x_r,
               int[] x_i) {
      real dydt[2];
      real input_signal; // Change from here!!!
      input_signal <- how_to(t, x_r, x_i); 
      dydt[1] <- y[2] + input_signal; // Change to here!!!
      dydt[2] <- -y[1] - theta[1] * y[2];
      return dydt;
}
```

the input signal is supposed to be a time series that is inputted - let's say I submit `input_signal_vector <- sin(t) + rnorm(T, sd=0.1)` (which is supposed to be a signal at the time points in `ts`) and I plan to use for `input_signal` the closest value in time.

The only way I can imagine is one could concat `ts` and `input_signal_vector` in x_r and then a search in this array.  But I can not imagine this is the *intended* use of these parameter.  It would also be extremely inefficient.

So if someone could show how such a case is supposed to be solved I would be very grateful.

Comment: I think you have the right intuition that you would have to pack all (real) inputs into the `x_r` array, but I don't think the cost of extraction would be noticeable relative to the cost of solving an ODE and doing the autodifferentiation. The `head`, `tail`, and `segment` functions are available, and as of Stan 2.9 you can do (almost) R-like subsetting with integers or integer arrays, such as `first:last`.

Comment: Too bad. But part of my confusion comes from the question how x_r is different from theta. Why did the author choose to use two arrays?

Comment: Essentially, x_r and x_i allow you to specify constant/fixed parameters that Stan does not learn about.  They are referred to as "data" in the manual, since everything that you are not learning about is "data".

Comment: Also, it would be better to send Stan related questions to the Stan users group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/stan-users